# Casper JS Logging and Downloading Once Submit Form

Tags: casperjs

I am trying to traverse a state database of court cases for homicides and other violent crimes research, using `Casper.JS`

The database works by the client first agreeing to Terms of Service via submitting an HTML form. After that a second form is presented in which you can enter in search terms to find up to 500 records in an HTML table.

This state database/site is very unreliable and often breaks down. The goal is to traverse it with Casper and host the data independently for a client.

My problem is that I can't get basic Casper tasks to work, besides loading the first form. It appears to be navigating, hits an `about:blank` and then stops. It doesn't log at critical junctures even though it is coded to do so.

The script I am running:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  clientScripts: [
    'jquery.min.js', // These two scripts will be injected in remote
    'moment.min.js' // DOM on every request
  ],
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false, // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
    loadPlugins: false // use these settings
  },
  logLevel: "debug",
  verbose: true // log messages will be printed out to the console
});
casper.start('http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/processDisclaimer.jis', function(status) {
  var y = (this)
  $("input[name='disclaimer']").prop('checked', true);
  $("input[name='action']").click();
  casper.log(y, 'info');
  setTimeout(function() {
    y.download('http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/inquiry-results.jsp?middleName=&partyType=&lastName=T&filingEnd=&filingDate=&site=00&filingStart=&d-16544-p=20&countyName=&action=Search&courtSystem=B&firstName=N&company=N', 'phantom.csv')
  }, 3000);
});

casper.run();
```

The output I am getting:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/processDisclaimer.jis, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/processDisclaimer.jis, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/processDisclaimer.jis"
[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected jquery.min.js client side
[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected moment.min.js client side
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2 http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/processDisclaimer.jis (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"
```

Can someone instruct me as to why I'm not getting my `console.log(y)` and why I have no download or error message? It just terminates once that output is given.

I should also mention that I believe the download will only work if the database server knows that I accepted the Terms, as in, I need to send my cookies to it in my download request. How does Casper handle that?

Thank you.

Comment: You should know: CasperJS [can't download more than 7 MB file](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/362), you must try with smallest-size files
Also read [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342285/unable-to-download-zip-file-from-url-with-casperjs)

Comment: @Igor I did not realize that was a limitation, that's too bad. :(